# Problem uploading Images to Firestore Storage

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I want to upload and image and upload a field on a firestore document so it stores the url's image.

To do that I have this code: 
This one uses the camera to take the photo.

```
selectImage(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let cameraOptions: CameraOptions = {
            destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            correctOrientation: true
        };

        this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions)
            .then((data) => {
            this.cameraImage = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data;
            resolve(this.cameraImage);
        });
    });
}
```

This one uploads the image and then updates a document setting up the url.

```
uploadProfilePhoto() {
    console.log(this.cameraImage)
    if (this.cameraImage != null) {


        this.image = 'profilePhoto' + new Date().getTime() + '.jpg';
        let storageRef: any;
        let parseUpload: any;
        storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('profilePhotos/' +
        this.image);
        parseUpload = storageRef.putString(this.cameraImage,
        'data_url');
        let ID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        console.log("ID")
        console.log(ID);
        parseUpload.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
            // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the
            download URL
            snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
                let profilePhoto = downloadURL
                this.firestore.doc(`users/${ID}`).update({
                    profilePhoto
                })
            });

        })
    }
}
```

When I run this code, It uploads the image perfectly, however sometimes it doesn't update the document and I cant find the reason.
I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

If I enter the link that error shows it show [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZr8e.jpg).

And it doesn't appear only 1 time, evey time I run this code, that error appears like 3-4 times.

Comment: Please don't link to images of text or code.  It's better to copy the text into the question so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: Also FYI: the new promise in selectImage isn't necessary.  You can just return the promise returned by `this.camera.getPicture().then()`.

Answer (score 2):

The message you're getting shows a "404", which is typically understood to be an HTTP response code meaning "not found".  The error is telling you that when you're calling getDownloadURL, the file is effectively not there.  This is because you haven't waited for the file to finish uploading.

When [`storageRef.putString()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#putString) returns, the file hasn't started to upload yet.  You can see from the linked API docs that it returns an [UploadTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask) object, which works like a Promise, because it has a then() method on it.  You need to use this UploadTask to determine when the upload is complete.  Only then will getDownloadURL work the way you expect.

Comment: Okay I get the image url, however im getting now this error: 
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined` . 

What I have now is something like  
`uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL)=> { })` inside the "complete" function() just like in UploadTask doc.

Comment: I don't know, sounds like a whole different problem now.